# Changing dependency of a inherited dependency

Tags: java, maven, jboss7.x

I'm using JBoss AS 7 with Maven, and also added RichFaces, that I'm almost sure, don't come with JBoss. So I added that to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But Richfaces also have its dependencies, so `cssparser` and `sac` also comes with compile scope, but they are also inside JBoss AS 7, so the following warning comes when I run JBoss:

```
Deployment "deployment.test.war" is using a private module ("org.w3c.css.sac:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
Deployment "deployment.test.war" is using a private module ("net.sourceforge.cssparser:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
```

I believe that this warning appears because I have this module both on my war and on JBoss, so I want to know: There is a way to change the scope of them to provided, in my POM? Even if they are inherited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change transitive dependencies' scopes. The best you can do is to exclude these dependencies using `<exclusions>` in your dependency declaration.

Comment: But excluding dependencies sometimes could break my code, couldn't it?

Comment: Of course, it can. But as you said, these dependencies are anyway provided by the cointainer or something. I didn't say it's the best way ever of doing things. Unfortunatelly, it's the best you can do with Maven.